# Send image to Flask server with React

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I want to transfer an image to the server, save a link to this image, and later upload this image to my products. But when I click the save button which sends the data to the server, I get an error 415 (UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE). How can I fix this?

My React file Product.jsx

```js
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "image") {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0],
      });
    } else {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formData.food_drink);
  }, [formData.food_drink]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("name", formData.name);
    postData.append("ingredients", formData.ingredients);
    postData.append("price", formData.price);
    postData.append("food_drink", formData.food_drink);
    postData.append("image", formData.image);

    fetch("/addProduct", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      body: postData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          food_drink: "pizza",
          ingredients: "",
          name: "",
          price: "",
          image: null,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

My Flask file srver.py

```py
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/addProduct', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    name = request.json["name"]
    ingredients = request.json["ingredients"]
    price = request.json["price"]
    food_drink = request.json["food_drink"]
    file_img = request.files["image"]
    print(file_img)
    if file_img:
        filename = secure_filename(file_img.filename)
        file_img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    db = sqlite3.connect('flask-server\db\main_db.db')
    sql = db.cursor()
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO products (name, ingredients, price, food_drink, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (name, ingredients, price, food_drink, (os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return jsonify({"message": "200"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Uploads folder I created in the root of the project from the server

Answer (score 1):

In case you send `multipart/form-data` or other object to Flask you cannot use `request.json` - this will raise 415 error. Instead please use `request.data`.

In case you still want to send some metadata along with image think of

1. passing it into request parameters.
2. Another idea is to zip metadata with image to one file on front end and parse it on backend
3. or use json with a field of transformed image to bytearray and then to string and unpack it on server

The valid example I found on https://harshalpagar.medium.com/image-upload-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-d4eccc631466, so you can use it as well and pass metadata you want in request body along with 'content' field

**Frontend** (I use reactjs, so fetch API goes out of the box, nevertheless the other code is in vanilla js)

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("paint-canvas");
let image_file = canvas.toDataURL()
let body = {
  "content": image_file,
}
fetch(uri, {
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(exception => {
  // fetch API problem: in case of CORS the server must send header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
  console.log(exception);
});
```

**Backend**

```
payload = request.json
image = payload['content']
# before ',' symbol there will be like 'data:image/png;base64', so you can understand image file
image = image[image.find(",") + 1:]  # get the image data from input
file_content = base64.b64decode(image)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
result = s3.meta.client.put_object(Body=file_content,
                                   Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
                                   Key="someimagename.png",
                                   Metadata={})
```